# Telerik RadGrid Sorting ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, telerik, telerik-grid

My Telerik RadGrid will not sort no matter what code I put in it. I have tried many things, and everytime I click on the headers, the arrow and color will change, but the data will stay in the same order. This is my latest chunk of code. (I got this from the Telerik website) Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="radProductsGrid" Skin="Default" AllowSorting="true"
AllowPaging="true" OnSortCommand="radProductsGrid_SortCommand" 
OnNeedDataSource="radProductsGrid_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns= "false"  
GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="false" PageSize="100">
<telerik:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="true" AllowFiltering="true" SortExpression="ItemNumber" DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText="Item Number" UniqueName="ItemNumber">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>      
<telerik:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="true" AllowFiltering="true" SortExpression="ProductName" DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" UniqueName="ProductName">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="true" AllowFiltering="true" SortExpression="CategoryName" DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category Name" UniqueName="CategoryName">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn> 

protected void radProductsGrid_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridTableView tableView = e.Item.OwnerTableView;
        if (e.SortExpression == "ItemNumber")
        {
            e.Canceled = true;
            GridSortExpression expression = new GridSortExpression();
            expression.FieldName = "ItemNumber";
            if (tableView.SortExpressions.Count == 0 || tableView.SortExpressions[0].FieldName != "ItemNumber")
            {
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
            }
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Descending)
            {
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending;
            }
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.None;
            }
            tableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
            tableView.Rebind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
tableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
tableView.Rebind();
```

Do this:

```
radProductsGrid.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
radProductsGrid.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 0):

check javascript onclick() event,it Drops Sort event

```
            var hasChanges, inputs, dropdowns, editedRow;

            function RowClick(sender, eventArgs) {
                if (editedRow && hasChanges) {
                    hasChanges = false;
                    if (confirm("Update changes?")) {

                        $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().updateItem(editedRow);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) 'Handles RadGrid1.NeedDataSource
    Dim RadGrid1 As RadGrid = CType(Page.FindControl("RadGrid1"), RadGrid)
    RadGrid1.DataSource = GetDataTable("SELECT کالا.شناسه, کالا.عنوان, کالا.پوشه, بارگیری, کالا.گروه_شناسه, گروه.عنوان AS گروه FROM کالا LEFT JOIN گروه ON کالا.گروه_شناسه = گروه.شناسه")
End Sub

Public Function GetDataTable(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
    Dim ConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
    adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    Dim table1 As New DataTable
    conn.Open()
    Try
        adapter.Fill(table1)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
    Return table1
End Function
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for your answer?